# regular expression in oracle for including number and period

Tags: regex, oracle

I need regular expression for which will remove all Non numeric character excluding.
means it only include
 Number
 perid (.)

can anybody help me.

Thank you.
Vijay Nalawade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
     REGEXP_REPLACE('your text 12.133', '[^0-9\.]','')
```

This will delete all non numeric and non dot characters.

**Please note:** `\` is required in front of `.` as `.` match any character. Details here: [Oracle Regular Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Regex `[0-9.]` matches only digits and `.`. Alternatively you can find replace other characters with an empty string using this regex: `[^0-9.]`

Comment: Hi Kirill, I'm having a problem, if the value in the character contains only dot (.) , I'll get an error since the column I'm using is Numeric and the dot is acceptable on it's own. 
example:      select to_number(REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello.', '[^0-9\.]','')) from dual ;